# Trouble with implementing function (recursive)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, recursion

The objective of the program is to enumerate all possible paths a person can take to get from a station A to a station L through a subway system without going over a track more than once. I know there are 640 possible paths as the instructor told us and we wrote this program as an earlier assignment in C using an adjacency matrix. Now the goal is to do the same, which is to enumerate all the possible routes and print out each route except to do it using classes (3 specifically: SubwaySystem, Station, and Track) WITHOUT using a matrix this time. Here is the schematic representation of the subway system itself.

[image]

I had a discussion with my TA about this program and how to approach it. He gave me some ideas such as using arrays to represent the stations and the tracks and I decided to use the approach I have shown in the entire code at the bottom of the post.

Let me show you the problematic areas of my code which I have been unable to solve (recursion is new to me).

```
 void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID)
{
        if(my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID == 33)  // Find a successful route to Station L.
//The condition is set to check for 33 because a track_starting_ID of 33 would correspond to station L.
        {
            count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
            cout << count_routes << " " << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //Print out this route
            return;
        }
        else //Get into recursive Function Body
        {
            for(int i = my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID; i < my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID + my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_size; i++)
            {
                if(my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited == 0)  //if this track is not visited before
                {
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 1; //mark this track as visited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 1; //mark its corresponding track as visited
                    cout << my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_1; //save this track
                    SearchRoute(Current_Station_ID++); //Recursive
                    i--; //Backtrack this track
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 0;//mark this track as unvisited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 0;//mark its corresponding track as unvisited
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me explain what the variables represent: 
**Current_Station_ID** is basically a counter like i.
 
**my_station** is an array of size 12 which hold all 12 stations.
 
**my_track** is an array of size 34 which hold all possible combinations of tracks between each respective station.
**track_starting_ID** represents the location at which a certain station's possible tracks begin within the my_track array. Sorry I'm not sure how to phrase this in an better way. For example, if you refer to the station array and track array I initialized in the SubwaySystem constructor in the entire code portion at the bottom of the post. You can see that **track_starting_ID** refers to the beginning location of where a certain station's track begins. i.e. a starting_ID of 0 corresponds to my_track[0] which is the beginning of the tracks leading from station "A" and a starting_ID of 1 refers to my_track(1) which is the beginning of the tracks leading from station "B". And a starting_ID of 6 corresponds to the tracks leading from station "C" in the my_track array at position [6]. And so on. (Hopefully this makes it clearer instead of more confusing).
**track_size** represents the number of tracks coming out of each station which you can see from the picture. For example the track size for station B would be 5 since there are 5 tracks sprouting out of station B.
**visited** and **node_1** and **node_2** are self explanatory. visited is a boolean variable which checks to see if a station has been visited and the nodes are stations on each side of the current track respectively.

The problem is I don't know how to fix the function for recursion to take place. I had a discussion with my TA about this a few days ago in which I told him what I was trying to accomplish with my function. We wrote some pseudo code together to make it clearer as to what the goal was with the function I was attempting to write which I have provided:

```
SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID)
{ 
     if ( ) //Find a successful route to Station L 
     { 
         … //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes” 
         … //Print out this route 
         return; 
     } 
     else //Get into recursive Function Body 
     { 
         //Use the track array to get all of its connected stations 
         for(int i = starting_ID; i < starting_ID + current size; i++) 
         { 
             if() // if this track is not visited before 
             { 
                 … //mark this track as visited 
                 … //mark its corresponding track as visited 
                 … //save this track 
                 SearchRoute( nextStaton_ID); // Recursive 
                 … //Backtrack this track 
                 … //mark this track as unvisited 
                 … //mark its corresponding track as unvisited 
             } 
         } 
     } 
}
```

This is what I understand the problem to be: I can't seem to properly implement my recursive function, SearchRoute, as I need to print the path, flag the path, and then unflag the path again to allow for backtracking. When I print out the final result I either get stuck in an infinite loop or get a single track such as A to B depending on what I try to put into the recursive call itself.

Here is the entire program excluding the recursive portion which I posted above for clarity sake:

```
//Function Declarations
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SUBWAY_H
#define SUBWAY_H

class Track
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Track();

    //Overload Constructor
    Track(char, char);

    //Destructor
    ~Track();

    //Member variables
    char node_1;  // node_1 and node_2 represent stations (for example
    char node_2;  // node_1 would be station A and node_2 would be station B)
    bool visited;
};

class Station
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Station();

    //Destructor
    ~Station();

    //Overload Constructor
    Station(char, int, int);

    //Member variables
    char station_name;
    int track_starting_ID;
    int track_size;
};

class SubwaySystem
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    SubwaySystem();

    //Destructor
    ~SubwaySystem();

    //Recursive function
    void SearchRoute(int);

    //Other member functions
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station);


    //Member variables
    Track my_track[34];
    Station my_station[12];

    int count_routes;
    int Current_Station_ID;

    //String to save found route
};

#endif

// **cpp**

//Function Definitions
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

Track::Track()
{
    visited = 0;
}


Track::~Track()
{
}


Track::Track(char pass_track1, char pass_track2)
{
    node_1 = pass_track1;
    node_2 = pass_track2;
    visited = false;
}


Station::Station()
{
}


Station::~Station()
{
}


Station::Station(char pass_station_name, int pass_start, int pass_size)
{
    station_name = pass_station_name;
    track_starting_ID = pass_start;
    track_size = pass_size;
}


SubwaySystem::SubwaySystem()
{
    //Initialize tracks
    //node_1, node_2
    my_track[0] = Track('a', 'b');
    my_track[1] = Track('b', 'a');
    my_track[2] = Track('b', 'c');
    my_track[3] = Track('b', 'd');
    my_track[4] = Track('b', 'e');
    my_track[5] = Track('b', 'f');
    my_track[6] = Track('c', 'b');
    my_track[7] = Track('c', 'e');
    my_track[8] = Track('d', 'b');
    my_track[9] = Track('d', 'e');
    my_track[10] = Track('e', 'b');
    my_track[11] = Track('e', 'c');
    my_track[12] = Track('e', 'd');
    my_track[13] = Track('e', 'g');
    my_track[14] = Track('e', 'h');
    my_track[15] = Track('f', 'b');
    my_track[16] = Track('f', 'h');
    my_track[17] = Track('g', 'e');
    my_track[18] = Track('g', 'k');
    my_track[19] = Track('h', 'e');
    my_track[20] = Track('h', 'f');
    my_track[21] = Track('h', 'i');
    my_track[22] = Track('h', 'j');
    my_track[23] = Track('h', 'k');
    my_track[24] = Track('i', 'h');
    my_track[25] = Track('i', 'k');
    my_track[26] = Track('j', 'h');
    my_track[27] = Track('j', 'k');
    my_track[28] = Track('k', 'g');
    my_track[29] = Track('k', 'h');
    my_track[30] = Track('k', 'i');
    my_track[31] = Track('k', 'j');
    my_track[32] = Track('k', 'l');
    my_track[33] = Track('l', 'k');
    //Initialize stations
    //station_name, track_starting_ID, track_size
    my_station[0] = Station('a', 0, 1);
    my_station[1] = Station('b', 1, 5);
    my_station[2] = Station('c', 6, 2);
    my_station[3] = Station('d', 8, 2);
    my_station[4] = Station('e', 10, 5);
    my_station[5] = Station('f', 15, 2);
    my_station[6] = Station('g', 17, 2);
    my_station[7] = Station('h', 19, 5);
    my_station[8] = Station('i', 24, 2);
    my_station[9] = Station('j', 26, 2);
    my_station[10] = Station('k', 28, 5);
    my_station[11] = Station('l', 33, 1);
    //Initiaize other members
    count_routes = 0;
    Current_Station_ID = 0;
}


SubwaySystem::~SubwaySystem()
{
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track)
{
    os << my_track.node_1 << '.' << my_track.node_2;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station)
{
    os << my_station.station_name << '.' << my_station.track_starting_ID << '.' << my_station.track_size;
    return os;
}


//This is where the above recursive function SearchRoute goes. I posted it separately so it's easier to read.



// **main**

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SubwaySystem findPaths;
    findPaths.SearchRoute(0);
}
```

Comment: Shorten the story, cut down to relevant code, and specifically point out the errors/issues please

Comment: How this question has 2 upvotes right after 1 minute?! It needs more that 2 minutes to read and also an hour to understand!

Comment: @MM me too, and another 30 minutes to understand the math/geometry or whatever the thing is that

Comment: I'm so sorry. I realize the post is painfully long. But I wanted to post all the information I could so to make it clearer for the answerer (I know this is not a word = )). If anyone could edit it to make it a more proper post. I would appreciate it. *Also thank you to whom ever upvoted this. That was fast.*

Comment: Just a style note.  Although you do not have the name the parameters when declaring a function you should do so as it makes the intent of those parameters much clearer to anyone reading the code.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll remember to do that next time. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Timonse The first two paragraphs of your question make nothing clearer to anyone here. If your question has exact duplicates, and they have a satisfactory answer, this one should be closed. If this one is asking about a different problem with the same assignment, or if the other questions got buried because of low quality, this question might have merit. It is of no concern to SO who is plagiarising whom and who the author of the code is - it's the job of moderation to enforce academic honesty or copyrights or anything like that.

Comment: Also, when implementing a search algorithm, I wouldn't try to flag-visit-unflag as a first approach. Copying the whole state then mutating the copy is more expensive but less error-prone. (Backtracking then becomes a depth-first-search of a tree of possible solution states - in your case partial paths through the subway system; the children of each node are the solutions that *advance* by one "step" - i.e. move down an unvisited track.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I initially was not going to post that part but only left it in because I felt people would think this is a duplicate question and therefore not answer. Regarding those other duplicates. They do not have satisfactory answers and therefore instead of editing and fix a post already thought to have been answered. I started a new one.  EDIT: Also you are free to take out the portions you feel are unnecessary which may make the post clearer to everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is a working solution, it gives 605 solutions, which I think is right

```
// RandomTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;






class Track
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Track();

    //Overload Constructor
    Track(char, char, int station, int opposite);

    //Destructor
    ~Track();

    //Member variables
    char node_1;  // node_1 and node_2 represent stations (for example
    char node_2;  // node_1 would be station A and node_2 would be station B)
    bool visited;

    int connected_station;
    int opposite_track;
};

class Station
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Station();

    //Destructor
    ~Station();

    //Overload Constructor
    Station(char, int, int);

    //Member variables
    char station_name;
    int track_starting_ID;
    int track_size;
};

class SubwaySystem
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    SubwaySystem();

    //Destructor
    ~SubwaySystem();

    //Recursive function
    void SearchRoute(int);

    //Other member functions
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station);


    //Member variables
    Track my_track[34];
    Station my_station[12];

    int count_routes;
    int Current_Station_ID;

    //String to save found route

    void SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID, int from_track_id, Track **currentPath, int pathCount);
};





// **cpp**


//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

Track::Track()
{
    visited = 0;
}


Track::~Track()
{
}


Track::Track(char pass_track1, char pass_track2, int station, int opposite)
{
    node_1 = pass_track1;
    node_2 = pass_track2;
    connected_station = station;
    opposite_track = opposite;

    visited = false;
}


Station::Station()
{
}


Station::~Station()
{
}


Station::Station(char pass_station_name, int pass_start, int pass_size)
{
    station_name = pass_station_name;
    track_starting_ID = pass_start;
    track_size = pass_size;
}


SubwaySystem::SubwaySystem()
{
    //Initialize tracks
    //node_1, node_2
    my_track[0] = Track('a', 'b', 1, 1);
    my_track[1] = Track('b', 'a', 0, 0);
    my_track[2] = Track('b', 'c', 2, 6);
    my_track[3] = Track('b', 'd', 3, 8);
    my_track[4] = Track('b', 'e', 4, 10);
    my_track[5] = Track('b', 'f', 5, 15);
    my_track[6] = Track('c', 'b', 1, 2);
    my_track[7] = Track('c', 'e', 4, 11);
    my_track[8] = Track('d', 'b', 1, 3);
    my_track[9] = Track('d', 'e', 4, 12);
    my_track[10] = Track('e', 'b', 1, 4);
    my_track[11] = Track('e', 'c', 2, 7);
    my_track[12] = Track('e', 'd', 3, 9);
    my_track[13] = Track('e', 'g', 6, 17);
    my_track[14] = Track('e', 'h', 7, 19);
    my_track[15] = Track('f', 'b', 1, 5);
    my_track[16] = Track('f', 'h', 7, 20);
    my_track[17] = Track('g', 'e', 4, 13);
    my_track[18] = Track('g', 'k', 10, 28);
    my_track[19] = Track('h', 'e', 4, 14);
    my_track[20] = Track('h', 'f', 5, 16);
    my_track[21] = Track('h', 'i', 8, 24);
    my_track[22] = Track('h', 'j', 9, 26);
    my_track[23] = Track('h', 'k', 10, 29);
    my_track[24] = Track('i', 'h', 7, 21);
    my_track[25] = Track('i', 'k', 10, 30);
    my_track[26] = Track('j', 'h', 7, 22);
    my_track[27] = Track('j', 'k', 10, 30);
    my_track[28] = Track('k', 'g', 6, 18);
    my_track[29] = Track('k', 'h', 7, 23);
    my_track[30] = Track('k', 'i', 8, 25);
    my_track[31] = Track('k', 'j', 9, 27);
    my_track[32] = Track('k', 'l', 11, 33);
    my_track[33] = Track('l', 'k', 10, 32);
    //Initialize stations
    //station_name, track_starting_ID, track_size
    my_station[0] = Station('a', 0, 1);
    my_station[1] = Station('b', 1, 5);
    my_station[2] = Station('c', 6, 2);
    my_station[3] = Station('d', 8, 2);
    my_station[4] = Station('e', 10, 5);
    my_station[5] = Station('f', 15, 2);
    my_station[6] = Station('g', 17, 2);
    my_station[7] = Station('h', 19, 5);
    my_station[8] = Station('i', 24, 2);
    my_station[9] = Station('j', 26, 2);
    my_station[10] = Station('k', 28, 5);
    my_station[11] = Station('l', 33, 1);
    //Initiaize other members
    count_routes = 0;
    Current_Station_ID = 0;
}


SubwaySystem::~SubwaySystem()
{
}



void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID, int from_track_id, Track **currentPath, int pathCount)
{
    if(my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID == 33)
    {
        count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
        cout << count_routes << " ";
        for(int i= 0; i < pathCount; i++)
        {
            cout << *currentPath[i]; 
        }
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    else //Get into recursive Function Body
    {
        for(int i = my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID; i < my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID + my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_size; i++)
        {
                    //check all the tracks that we have visited before
            bool visited = false;
            for(int n = 0; n < pathCount; n++)
            {
                if(currentPath[n] == &my_track[i] || i == currentPath[n]->opposite_track) visited = true;
            }


            if(!visited)
            {
                int nextStation = my_track[i].connected_station;
                currentPath[pathCount] = &my_track[i];
                SearchRoute(nextStation, i, currentPath, pathCount + 1); 
            }
        }  
    }
}




ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track)
{
    os << my_track.node_1 << '.' << my_track.node_2;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station)
{
    os << my_station.station_name << '.' << my_station.track_starting_ID << '.' << my_station.track_size;
    return os;
}


//This is where the above recursive function SearchRoute goes. I posted it separately so it's easier to read.



// **main**


//#include "subway.h"






int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Track *tempTracks[34];
    SubwaySystem findPaths;
    findPaths.SearchRoute(0, -1, tempTracks, 0);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are sure it is 640 then check that all the links between stations and tracks are correct.

Comment: Joe you are the greatest person ever. Thank you soooooooooooooooo much for taking out your time to help me. I'm trying to see how this works now.

Comment: I feel bad about constantly bugging you but your the last person I can turn to right now. I have a question why do you have a function getchar() in main? It's not defined anywhere. Also I keep getting an error while trying to print out cout << *currentPath[i]; I think its because of the pointer but I'm not too sure.

Comment: getchar() is just so that the console window doesn't close. You can just take that out.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an error from using the pointer.. Try just printing out the parts of the object. Like: cout << currentPath[i]->node_2;

Comment: It may be because the overloads for << are defined after the function. Try moving the two operator<< functions above the SearchRoute function, or put them in your header file not the cpp file.

Comment: The first method cout << currentPath[i]->node_2; did the trick. Thanks again. Now all I have to do is figure out why I'm not getting 640, I'm cross checking the tracks and stations right now and so far they seem to be correct.

Comment: I GOT IT!!! my_track[27] = Track('j', 'k', 10, 30); the 30 should be 31 and BAM the answer is 640. Honestly I have no idea how to thank you for your trouble. I mean saying thank you isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is here:

```
my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 1; //mark this track as visited
my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 1; //mark its corresponding track as visited
cout << my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_1; //save this track
SearchRoute(Current_Station_ID++); <<<<<<<< PROBLEM 
i--; //Backtrack this track  <<<<<<< Also this will do nothing
my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 0; <<<<<<< Now Current_Station_ID is 1 more than you are expecting it to be.
my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 0;//mark its corresponding track as unvisited
```

You do Current_Station_ID++ in the middle of the block, and then you use it again as if it was the same value as before, the ++ operator is actually increasing the value of Current_Station_ID by 1.

You also don't need the locking this item to happen in the for loop. So it should go something like this:

```
void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID, int from_track_id, Track *currentPath, int pathCount)
{
    if(my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID == 33)
    {
        count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
        cout << count_routes << " ";
        for(int i= 0; i < pathCount; i++)
        {
             cout << my_track[i]; 
        }
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    else //Get into recursive Function Body
    {

         if(from_track_id >= 0) my_track[from_track_id].visited = 1; 

        for(int i = my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID; i < my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID + my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_size; i++)
        {
            int nextStation = my_track[i].node_2;   ///<<<<<<< But you will need to change node_2 to be an int, and use the station number, not letter when you set them up
            if(my_track[i].visited == 0)
            {
                currentPath[pathCount] = my_track[i];
                SearchRoute(nextStation, i, currentPath, pathCount + 1); 


            }
        }

       if(from_track_id >= 0) my_track[from_track_id].visited = 0; 
    }
}
```

Then in your main function do this:

```
int main()
{
    Track tempTracks[34];
    SubwaySystem findPaths;
    findPaths.SearchRoute(0, -1, tempTracks, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I thought the i-- would help in backtracking. The problem is when I try to implement your version of the code the program gets stuck in an infinite loop in the first case when still using Current_Station_ID. In the second case using i, program gives an enormous number.

Comment: Also make sure that you are using i in the if statement too. if(my_track[i].visited == 0)

Comment: The infinite loop in the first case will be because Current_Station_ID is not being changed when the if statement is false. I will add it to the answer

Comment: First off, thank you for trying to help me. Now the program crashes. It may be easier for you to check the results if you run it on your computer if you have a c++ compiler (you don't have to I'm willing to test it). Also out of curiosity what it the function of i+1 in the recursive call when i is being incremented in the for loop itself. And I have noticed another problem in my code. I'm using the same counter (Current_Station_ID) for both the my_station array and my_track array which are both of different sizes. Maybe you can help me fix that unless that doesn't matter. EDIT: I'll try again.

Comment: Ok, now I get a total route count of 89 which means we are getting closer = ). I was getting only 1 a while ago. But it's still not completely correct since the total possible routes are 640.

Comment: There is more wrong to this, you also need to be testing if the station has been visited, not the track

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is now. But I think you may be right about checking stations instead of tracks. The thing is that my visited variable is located within the track class so I'm not sure how to check the stations themselves. Maybe my approach was wrong..

Comment: Ok I have made some more changes.

Comment: Basically you need to test if a station has been visited, not a track, and then the tracks should be stored as a list of links between stations.

Comment: Update: I did what you said. I moved the variable visited to the station class. Changed node_2 to int and changed the my_track array to reflect int's instead of char now for node_2. However, it still isn't recurring correctly. I've been studying the code you posted and I can't see where the error lies. Do you think its possible that the condition for incrementing count_routes++ could be incorrect?

Comment: The other issue is writing out the paths, at the moment it will write them as a tree structure. As this is how a recursive function works, so it would write out. "a, b, c, e, g, k, l" but then "i, j, h, i, k, l, j, k" because it is following along the tree. What you need is on every success to write out the list of stations used to get there. So you will have to record this information and pass it along the recursion chain.

Comment: You should also move the visited back onto the track, because you want all paths, not combinations. It is still pretty similar to what you have, just with the way that it is now it won't do the path, "a, b, e, d, b, f, h, k, l" because b is repeated twice.

Comment: Thank you for still helping. To record would I need another array to save the tracks and then print them out? Also when you say to move visited back onto the track. Do you mean I will have to check track along with station?

Comment: I have updated it again. I should really do some real work hahaha

Comment: Wow your truly amazing. I'll retry now = )

Comment: Hey, Joe I'm wondering have you tried to run this on your machine? I'm wondering if its just my computer or what since the output still isn't producing all the paths.

Comment: I think the final problem is that your tracks allow for 2 way travel, I tried running it and it lists way too many possibles. Which is because you can travel like "a, b, a". So you need to mark the track as visited in both directions. You will need to structure your data in a different way to do this. Like have the station object contain a list of pointers to track objects.

Comment: you could add an extra number to the track, which is its opposite direction track, then set the current track, and the opposite track to visited as you run through it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That may work. I'll try adding an extra number to the track. Oh and before I forget were you able to get 640 possible routes? I couldn't.

Comment: That actually makes it more complicated then I thought.. I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I found 640 routes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *connectom[] = {
"B",            // A
"ACDEF",        // B
"BE",           // C
"BE",           // D
"CDBGH",        // E
"BH",           // F
"EK",           // G
"EFJKI",        // H
"HK",           // I
"HK",           // J
"HIJGL",        // K
"K"             // L
};

char tracks[0x100];
char strout[0x100];

void path(char x, char *s) {
  *s++ = x;
  if(x == 'L') {
    *s = 0;
    printf("path=%s\n", strout);
  } else {
    for(const char *p = connectom[x - 'A']; *p; p++) {
       unsigned char track_ndx = x > *p? (x << 4) ^ *p : (*p << 4) ^ x;
       if(tracks[track_ndx] == 0) {
         tracks[track_ndx] = 1;
         path(*p, s);
         tracks[track_ndx] = 0;
       } // if
    } // for
  } // else
} // path

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  path('A', strout);
} // main
```

Comment: Wow nice. That's one way of doing it. What made it kind of difficult for me was utilizing all 3 classes and of course the recursive function.